# Dificuldade no tratamento da query

Tags: php, mysql, array

Pessoal eu tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT p.ra, p.nomealuno, 
qa.respostaaluno, q.respostacorreta
FROM prova p
INNER JOIN questoes_aluno qa
ON qa.idprova = p.id
INNER JOIN questao q
ON q.id = qa.idquestao
AND q.iddisciplina = 46
ORDER BY p.id ASC;
```

E ela gera esse resultado:

[image]

Agora eu preciso pegar as várias respostas do aluno e compará-las para gerar uma tabela com a média dele.

Exemplo:

**RA    | Aluno | Média** 
111   | Fulano |  5

Já tentei comparar os RA's (que são identificadores únicos), guardar os iguais em uma array e depois comparar as respostas, mas não deu certo, pq ele não está salvando os alunos iguais nessa array.

OBS: A quantidade de respostas do aluno pode variar, então cada aluno pode ter de 1 a 5 respostas dependendo da disciplina, mas em uma query, sempre vão haver o mesmo número de respostas por aluno.

Esquema da Tabela:
[image]

Alguém pode me ajudar e me dar uma luz de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Pode postar as estruturas das tabelas?

um jeito de conseguir o que vc quer é fazer um COUNT onde respostaaluno = respostacorreta, agrupado por ra, e depois outro COUNT para ver quantas respostas cada aluno deu.

Ai depois vc divide esses 2 counts e diz a nota.

Comment: @WilliamBrunoRochaMoraes Essa é a estrutura da tabela: http://i.imgur.com/muNqst9.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar, em geral:

```
SELECT
  ( ( SUM( IF(respostaaluno = respostacorreta, 1, 0) ) / COUNT(id) ) * 10 ) as Media
FROM
  Respostas
GROUP BY `ra`
```

[Veja isso clicando aqui.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/475bc8/3)

**Explicação:**

```
IF(respostaaluno = respostacorreta, 1, 0)
```

Se a resposta do aluno for correta irá resultar em 1 e se não resultará em 0.

```
SUM(...)
```

Irá somar todos os dados gerados anteriormente, somando todos os "1", assim obtendo todos os acertos.

```
COUNT(id)
```

Irá contar a quantidade de respostas que existem.

```
* 10
```

Multiplicará por 10 para gerar um média de 0 até 10 ao invés de 0 até 1.

**Editado:**

No seu caso acredito que poderia usar algo similar a isto:

```
SELECT 
p.ra, 
p.nomealuno, 
( ( SUM( IF(qa.respostaaluno = q.respostacorreta, 1, 0) ) / COUNT(qa.id) ) * 10 ) as Media
FROM prova p
INNER JOIN questoes_aluno qa
ON qa.idprova = p.id
INNER JOIN questao q
ON q.id = qa.idquestao
AND q.iddisciplina = 46
GROUP BY p.ra
ORDER BY p.id ASC;
```

Comment: Cara.. o problema é que não tenho essa tabela respostas, o esquema da tabela é esse:  http://i.imgur.com/muNqst9.png

Comment: Você editar para ficar melhor, nos comentários é difícil.

Comment: Valeu @inkeliz !! Tô aprendendo aqui